# JQuery: Comparing two multi-line strings, one pulled from HTML - not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, comparison

I have a maddeningly simple task (and be patient with me, I'm new to all this): I have a div with a table inside, and the table contains one row and two cells, side-by-side. One cell contains header text, the next cell contains a paragraph of body text. It looks great on large screens, bad on small ones. So when the viewport width goes below 890px, I want to pile the two on top of each other by breaking the cells into two different rows.

First, just let me say that, yes, I have to use the table. I know using tables for layout is clunky, but it's necessary for vertically centering everything inside the div.

So my solution to this problem was to write some JQuery that would take the current contents of the table, fetched using the `html()` method, compare them to the "initial state" contents of the table (at larger viewport widths), and then replace the contents with a "final state" string that just has `</tr><tr>` inserted after the first cell's `</td>` tag.

The variable containing the initial state table contents is exactly the same as the table contents returned by the `html()` method but with `\n\` at the end of each line except the last (the extra backslash to tell JS that it's a multiline string). I ran a `strcmp` on the strings in MATLAB to ensure I didn't make any stupid mistakes, came back true. And when I ask JS to print both strings to the console, they look identical. But when I ask JS if they're `==`, I get a false.

So I made a second variable for the initial state with `\r\n\` instead of `\n\` because I read that some browsers do newlines differently. Checked if the current table contents were equal to either of them. Nope.

What's going on here?

Comment: How far back are you supporting browsers? If you only need this on "modern" browsers there's better ways to vertically and/or horizontally center content, see: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ (you can check if the browser supports these techniques with http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: @Kaitlyn Brown Is it possible that you could create a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net)? Also you saying "I want to pile the two on top of each other" so you want left one up and below that the right one?

Comment: All I want to do is insert the </tr><tr> to make a new row between the two elements. The string comparison problem is preventing that.

Comment: Your question is too compressed. Need some more parts to understand people here. It feels like lot to take in. Sorry to say that. I suggest to break it in parts.

Answer (score 1):

Tables should not be used for page layout. There are tons of css tricks to align a div and the contents inside. and for the responsive design you can use bootstrap. See [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or you can use media query to write your own responsive design. bootstrap code should look like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">

            //some code for part1

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">

            //some code for part1

    </div>
</div>
```

or write your own responsive CSS using media query..
HTML code is :

```
<div> <!-- header wrapper -->
 <div class="menu1 col-1">
    //some code
 </div>
 <div class="menu2 col-2">
    //some code
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS file will be:

```
.menu1,menu2 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
}
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
 /* For desktop: */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
}
```

hope this will help you in design..